# Why my iPhone6 is not be able to connect with my PC?

Tags: iphone, photos, import

I have an iPhone6 and I want to import photos or videos in my computer ASUS zenbook ux31ua/gl100t but I don't know why in my iPhone6 doesn't appear the permit to connect with it and consequently neither in Desktop. 
How should I do to transer photos from iPhone6 to my PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to connect it through iTunes.

It is the only way apple's portable devices can connect with workstations and it has been this way since their introduction. Think of iTunes as the managing app for your iPod|iPhone|iPad...